# Yocto build for a static library fails with error "No Match Found"

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, libraries, yocto

I am trying to include a Yocto recipe in the image which I wrote for static library.

1. Created recipes-test/static folder in my own layer .
2. Created 'static_0.1.bb' file in this folder
3. Created 'files' folder inside the 'recipes-test/static' folder
4. Copied the below files.

hello.c

```
char * hello (void)
{
  return "Hello";
}
```

world.c

```
char *world(void)
{
  return "World";
}
```

helloworld.h

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_H
#define HELLOWORLD_H
char * hello (void);
char * world (void);
#endif
```

5. Created recipe with the following content:

DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld example static library"
    LICENSE = "MIT"
    LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
    SRC_URI = " file://hello.c \
               file://world.c \
               file://helloworld.h "

```
S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
        ${CC} -c hello.c world.c
        ${AR} -cvq libhelloworld.a hello.o world.o
}

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${includedir}
        install -d ${D}${libdir}
        install -m 0755 helloworld.h ${D}${includedir}
        install -m 0755 libhelloworld.a ${D}${libdir}
}
```

When i say `bitbake static` , static library is created in the tmp/work folder

When i included it in conf/local.conf file with the following line:
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " static"

The build fails at the root file creating stage with the following error:

```
not found other for: 
not found modules for: 
not found deltainfo for: 
not found updateinfo for: 
oe-repo: using metadata from Tue 02 Jul 2019 03:54:50 AM UTC.
No module defaults found
No match for argument: static
Error: Unable to find a match
```

Can you please help me to resolve the error

Update: After changing IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " static-staticdev", i get the following error:

```
No module defaults found
--> Starting dependency resolution
--> Finished dependency resolution
Error: 
 Problem: package static-staticdev-0.1-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4 requires static-dev = 0.1-r0, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides static = 0.1-r0 needed by static-dev-0.1-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yocto will automatically split up the files installed in `${D}` into different packages. In your case the helloworld.h will go into `${PN}-dev` (`${PN}` equals static in your case, but I write ${PN} to avoid confusion) and libhelloworld.a will go into `${PN}-staticdev`, but since there's no other files there will not be a package called `${PN}` since it would be empty.

If you really want the static library to end up in the image, use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "static-staticdev"`

There's also a problem that there is no file that will be included in the plain `${PN}` package, which with the default settings means that no such package will be created. This is a problem since the `${PN}-dev` package has a runtime dependency on `${PN}`. This can be solved by allowing the creation of `${PN}` even if it's empty, enable this by adding `ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. After updating to static-staticdev, i get a new error. How can I debug this

Comment: @md.jamal Updated the answer to include the solution to your new error.