# Yocto bitbake build error when adding fftw package

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using Yocto Warrior release to build linux for Dart-imx8m SOM. Documentation can be found here : https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=DART-MX8M_Yocto&release=RELEASE_WARRIOR_V1.1_DART-MX8M.

I want to add fftw package whose recipe is in meta-oe layer. Whenever I add this package in my local.conf file, I get an error with bitbake regarding a dnf related task.

I add the package like this in my **local.conf** file : `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " fftw"`

I get the following error when building image with **bitbake fsl-image-gui** :

```
ERROR: fsl-image-gui-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install packagegroup-core-tools-profile packagegroup-fsl-tools-audio packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear tree rpm packagegroup-fsl-tools-benchmark boost gstreamer1.0 packagegroup-fsl-tools-gpu packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer1.0 psplash gpsd packagegroup-base-extended collectd kernel-image-4.19.35-imx8mq+gdc7a2fd packagegroup-core-tools-testapps packagegroup-core-boot tcf-agent packagegroup-fsl-tools-gpu-external packagegroup-core-full-cmdline packagegroup-tools-bluetooth packagegroup-fsl-tools-testapps opencv fftw libsdl-1.2-0 packagegroup-fsl-gstreamer1.0-full lftp packagegroup-core-tools-debug libgpiod2 dnf weston-init run-postinsts mosquitto packagegroup-core-nfs-server sshfs-fuse spitools kernel-devicetree android-tools htop poco tmux openssh-sftp-server weston-xwayland xterm locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.1.0
cachedir: /home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for: 
not found modules for: 
not found deltainfo for: 
not found updateinfo for: 
oe-repo: using metadata from Wed 28 Oct 2020 09:16:57 AM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Wed 28 Oct 2020 09:16:57 AM UTC.
No module defaults found
No match for argument: fftw
Error: Unable to find a match

ERROR: fsl-image-gui-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: 
ERROR: fsl-image-gui-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/build_xwayland/tmp/work/imx8mq_var_dart-poky-linux/fsl-image-gui/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.2614
ERROR: Task (/home/safetyn/safetynYoctoGenerator/warrior/var-fsl-yocto/sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-sdk/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-gui.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Woud you have any clue where this error come from ?

Thanks,

Paul

**Edit** :

Found a way to make it compile for those who are intereseted. (inspired by [Yocto build for a static library fails with error "No Match Found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845122/yocto-build-for-a-static-library-fails-with-error-no-match-found))

I edited my *.bb file and added `ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"`

I am not sure I got it completely but it looks like dnf package manager needs folders created for all added packages even if empty.
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-ALLOW_EMPTY

Comment: Note that the ALLOW_EMPTY change will probably not include any files in your rootfs.  What happens is that the RPM fftw is created without any files. Without ALLOW_EMPTY, no such RPM files are created.  Now that you have a RPM it will be installed, but what is the point?

Comment: Yes, I realize now that the workaround was useless. My misunderstanding was that fftw was a recipe but these are the packages that I am interested in (libfftw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [fftw recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-support/fftw/fftw_3.3.8.bb?h=warrior) is set up to create a few different packages (RPM) like libfftw, libfftwl, libfftwf, fftw-wisdom, fftwl-wisdom, fftwf-wisdom, and fftw-wisdom-to-conf.
You probably want to add one or more of those.  It seems there is no actual fftw package.

It is important to remember that IMAGE_INSTALL and RDEPEND lists items from the package namespace, while DEPENDS lists items from the recipe namespace.

If you are unsure about which package you want to install you can inspect the packages-split folder for fftw in tmp/work to see which files are included in which package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, you made things a lot clearer for me !
I just want to ask : how can I list available packages before compilation, is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Each recipe lists it packages in the PACKAGES variable. So 'bitbake -e fftw | grep PACKAGES' should show you what packages are available.  What files are put in each package is expressed with globs in the FILES_<packagename> variables such as FILE_${PN} or FILES_libfftw.