# Yocto build could not invoke dnf . command && no Match for the argument : recipe-name

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I tried to build my custom recipe for the project which contains programs for sensors. All the task and library making is taken care of by CMakeLists.txt it also has python dependencies. I added all the required dependencies within my recipe and tried to build it using the "bitbake soofierecp" command execution got successful. Whereas while attempting to install it with the local.conf using "IMAGE_INSTALL += soofierecp" it is giving an error as listed below:

Error is:

```
ERROR: soofie-img-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Could not invoke dnf. Command '/home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/dnf -v --rpmverbosity=info -y -c /home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/dnf/dnf.conf --setopt=reposdir=/home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/yum.repos.d --installroot=/home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/rootfs --setopt=logdir=/home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/temp --repofrompath=oe-repo,/home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo --nogpgcheck install i2c-tools packagegroup-base-extended packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-core-ssh-dropbear psplash python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-requests run-postinsts soofierecp usbutils locale-base-en-us locale-base-en-gb' returned 1:
DNF version: 4.12.0
cachedir: /home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
User-Agent: falling back to 'libdnf': could not detect OS or basearch
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
oe-repo: using metadata from Thu 26 May 2022 05:31:19 AM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Thu 26 May 2022 05:31:20 AM UTC.
No match for argument: soofierecp
Error: Unable to find a match: soofierecp
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/anvation/nitish/source/build/tmp/work/qemux86_64-poky-linux/soofie-img/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.1379711
ERROR: Task (/home/anvation/nitish/workspace/meta-soofie/recipes-example/images/soofie-img.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 4873 tasks of which 4872 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed. "added the meta-layer in bblayer.conf file"
```

Recipe is:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

PR = "r0"

DEPENDS = "openssl python3-six-native python3-pytest-runner-native"

SRC_URI = "\
           file://src/ \
           file://third_party/pybind11/ \
           file://third_party/CLI11/ \
           file://third_party/c-periphery/ \
           file://CMakeLists.txt \
          "
do_configure() {
        cmake ../
}
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "python-requests python-six"

inherit pkgconfig cmake python3native

EXTRA_OEMAKE = ""
ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN}="1"
FILES_${PN} = "${bindir}/*"
DEPENDS += "udev"
```

Please help me to reach for the solution
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56845122/yocto-build-for-a-static-library-fails-with-error-no-match-found it is probably the same issue.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I checked and did the same recipe and it got built successfully also the image but it doesn't contain the executable file which I made using cmake. whereas I checked the WORKDIR there is a build folder that contains all the executable and binaries. i don't know how to include all files in the package of the recipe. @Falital

Comment: You need to add the do_install task and install your artifacts there. For example do_install () {
       install -d ${D}${bindir}
       install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/helloyp ${D}${bindir}/
}
FILES_${PN} += "${D}${bindir}/"

Comment: thank you so much able to add the executable with the image and run it with the boot image @Falital

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the above code working with the suggestion and help
Thank you so much
The updated recipe is:

'

```
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
    
    S = "${WORKDIR}"
    
    PR = "r0"
    
    SRC_URI = "\
               file://src/ \
               file://third_party/pybind11/ \
               file://third_party/CLI11/ \
               file://third_party/c-periphery/ \
               file://CMakeLists.txt \
              "
    inherit cmake pkgconfig python3native
    
    DEPENDS += "openssl python3-six-native python3-pytest-runner-native"
    EXTRA_OECMAKE = ""
    
    do_install() {
            install -d ${D}${bindir}
            install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/build/datagen ${D}${bindir}
    }
    
    DEPENDS += "udev"
    FILES_${PN} += "${D}${bindir}/"
    ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"
```

'